# How to link JOGL with PowerVR OpenGL ES 2.0 and EGL version?

Tags: java, opengl-es, jogl

How can i link JOGL - Java binding for OpenGL with openGL ES 2.0 library like PowerVR OpenGL ES 2.0 lib and egl on windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we just have to drop PowerVR libs and dlls in front of %PATH% in windows 7

JOGL has in built integration for these